# Google chrome not loading properly on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome

Google Chrome is not loading properly. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, with no success. I rebooted, no success. Deleted the personal file, with no success.  Icons are not showing [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVRPW.png).

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1442633

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** When you say that Google Chrome is not loading properly, what does that mean? Are you getting any error messages? Are there any warnings/errors when you try to run Chrome from command line (`google-chrome`)? Please edit your question directly with the outcome. Thanks